# Kalman fitler to estimate position from velocity measurement

Tags: kalman-filters, bayesian-estimation

I am using the Kalman filter to estimate the position from velocity measurements. I implemented the filter, but the position estimate is not well enough (large RMSE and Covariance value). Some time ago, I estimated the velocity using the position measurements (vice versa of the previous case) and the results were satisfying. What could be the reason that the former case doesn't work well enough?

Edit: Let me re-introduce the problem. Suppose I design a robot and I need to estimate its position and velocity using a tachometer. (And yes I know the initial position.) Then, my state variables become

```
x = [p v] 
p: position
v: velocity
```

Since the tachometer provides a velocity measurement (i.e. pulse per unit time presumably 1 sec), my measurement vector become

```
y = [v].
```

Now I assume that my robot make constant velocity moves and crease a CV model for it motion. Assume F,H,Q and R matrices are standard CV motion matrices. To summarize I have measurement of velocity and trying to estimate the position and velocity of the robot. When I use Kalman filter for that problem I have bad position estimates. However, apart from that problem, when I try to estimate the speed from the position measurement, I have nice results for the velocity. My question is about this difference. In the first case I have velocity measurement and I have bad estimates for the position. In the second case I have position measurements but I have nice speed estimates. Although, both measurements are indirect why do I have such a bad estimate when I try to estimate the position from velocity? Am I doing a nonsense thing by estimating the position from velocity measurement?

One possible answer could be: When I try to estimate the position from velocity measurements I integrate the error. However, when I try to estimate the velocity from position measurements I differentiate the error. Therefore the former provides bad results.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you have done, we have a limited ability to help. There could be lots of things, but finding the right one is harder without more information.

Comment: How do you initialize the position estimate?  Because the velocity is the derivative of the position, you won't be able to get absolute position correctly without some other information. That should result in an offset from the true position, which will then give large RMSE and covariance.

Comment: @Irreducible I think I gave enough details of my problem. Instead of making irrelevant comments you might tell what is lack in the question like Peter did.

Comment: @Peter K. my initial point for both position and speed is zero. As long as I determine my initial points, I think I might have position estimates, or I don't?

Comment: My subjective opinion is that you have not added enough information for anything. You are stating in a bigger context what you are doing but missing all the details. Showing your code would help people to see how you approach this problem.

Comment: I also agree with @Irreducible : Showing code or data (or both) will help get a sensible answer.

Comment: @Irreducible my problem is not related with the code at all. This is only a theoretical question. Of course, I can share my code but then people will miss the point. I am only saying that If you have position measurements you might estimate the velocity well enough. Are there any **theoretical** obstacle to estimate the position from velocity measurement?

Comment: Dear all,  here is the signal processing field (not stackoverflow), why are you asking about the code? I am not asking you to correct my code?

Comment: With Kalman filters, the devil is in the details, and people very commonly mistake the word Kalman for magic. So, we asked for details both to see what you're doing, and if you have a hope of succeeding. As to your comment about giving us code, I would much rather that you give us the detailed math than the detailed code, because that way I don't have to plow through your code to figure out the math.

Comment: Your reasoning is plausible. Integration of measured velocity is prone to accumulated bias errors, whereas differentiation of measured position would introduce instantaneous errors only. So given everything else being the same, you can expect more error in the former.

Comment: I am waiting for the ones who are asking for details. Now, I gave enough details. I will be dissapointed about this platform if anyone asking about details doesn't make any comment.